# Free ASP.net tool for scheduling

Tags: asp.net, scheduling

I need Free tools for scheduling tasks in ASP. Net C#.

I tried with ASP. Net Calendar control, But it's not too flexible to handle all the aspects of requirements. Say Calender events based on Users, Based on some external types, etc. May be I need to learn some sort of AJAX before doing the experiment with Calender control.

Before that, Is there any free tools available? So I can plug-in that directly with little modification or configuration?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [DayPilot Lite](http://www.daypilot.org/daypilot-lite.html). **DayPilot Lite** is an open-source version of DayPilot. It is helping thousands of users to build calendar, personal scheduling, and resource booking applications.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a good open source.

Comment: Is there any tools than Daypilot, that support change color, grouping and mobile view ?